# Can I pass a DEFINED constant to a function through a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, constants

I have the following code:

```
DEFINE('DEFINEDTESTVAR', 'Hello World');

function callit($callVar) {
  echo "The call is ".$callVar;
}


$passthis = 'DEFINEDTESTVAR';
callit($passthis);
```

I know I can do `callit(DEFINEDTESTVAR)` but that's not what I am looking to do. Is it possible?

Comment: If that's not what you want to do, when what *do* you want to do? The approach that you have rejected without explanation is the solution to the question in your title.

Comment: That's the first time in my 5 years writing PHP that I've seen `define()` written in uppercase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either pass the constant itself:

```
$passthis = DEFINEDTESTVAR;
```

Or access it through [`constant()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) which allows you to test for null in case it isn't defined (for undefined constants, passing the constant literally results in a string with the constant name):

```
$passthis = constant('DEFINEDTESTVAR');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
define('DEFINEDTESTVAR', 'Hello World'); // you should use define

function callit($callVar) {
  echo "The call is ".$callVar;
}    

$passthis = DEFINEDTESTVAR; // no need to use quotes
callit($passthis);
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter whether it's `define` or `DeFiNe` or `dEFINE` or `DEFINE`. I was just pointing out how unconventional it is to write it in uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a constant's value from a string with constant(). It will return null if the named constant is not found.

```
$passthis = constant('DEFINEDTESTVAR');
callit($passthis);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
DEFINE('DEFINEDTESTVAR', 'Hello World');

function callit($callVar) {
  echo "The call is ".$callVar;
}


$passthis = DEFINEDTESTVAR;
callit($passthis);
```